# motion tween movie clip

Tags: flash, flash-cs5

I am making a motion tween with the timeline and it works with a movieclip.
My Issue is that can I use as3 as well?
I have 24 frames for the simple motion tween and when I click on "actions" in flash6 to as3 editing area I cant?

I wan to be able to click on the movie clip like a hyperlink to load another webpage.

Is this because you cant do both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place your all action script code in a separate layer.
Because in AS3 you can not apply any code directly to the display object.
Here is few line of code, i used for ball_mc -

```
import flash.net.navigateToURL;

    var link:String = 'http://www.google.com';

    ball_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick);

    function onClick(event:MouseEvent):void {
        //trace('click');
        navigateToURL(new URLRequest(link));
    }
```

Comment: the movie clip mc1 is undefined ? it is in the library and dragged on to the stage?

Comment: I checked, same code it is working fine for me even though if i will drag from library. if in your animated movieClip contains other object, then apply this prperty, mc1.mouseChildren = false;